# Express: req.params returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, reactjs, express

got simple get method on server side which is using url params, and client side request for that url (react), but problem is that server is returning undefined for that params. here is code:

Server (index.js) :

```
router.use('/api/info/:name/:id', require('./info'))`
```

info.js:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
try {
   const name = req.params.name;
   const id = req.params.id;
   console.log('name ' + name +'  id  ' + id)

    return res.status(200).send({
       id: id,
       name: name
    })
} catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).send({
      message: err.message
    })
  }
})
```

and client side (ReactJS):

```
componentDidMount(){
 const { match: { params } } = this.props;
    axios.get(`/api/recipe/${params.name}/${params.id}`)              
      .then(res => res.data)
      .then(data =>{
         console.log(data)
    })      
}
```

and as i said this code returns undefined for both name and id on server side but client side works (i logged it and it is valid). in console it gives me this error too (DevTools's console)

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500

What is wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The route you're defining in `index.js` is `/api/info/title/:id` but you're making the API call to `/api/recipe/${params.name}/${params.id}`. Your route doesn't match and you're not defining `:name` as a param.

Unless this is a typo on your end, changing your `router.use` code to match your API call should work:

```
router.use('/api/recipe/:name/:id', require('./info'));
```

Comment: In your React code, your `.get` code is hitting `api/recipe` and not `api/info` as you have defined in your server. You're hitting the wrong endpoint.

Comment: oh sorry i wish i could delete my post. problem is that i modified my url param names to post here and i forgot to modify recipe to info

Answer (score 0):

You're not telling Express to expect parameters (see "parameters" section [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)), you'll need something like this:

```
router.get('/:name/:id', async (req, res) => { ... })
```